# Sharepoint online Geolocation

Tags: geolocation

Our company has numerous facilities across the country, each with their own set of policies/procedures. I'd like to add each facility to a SharePoint map, and then when a user clicks on the site, they are taken to the SharePoint list associated with the facility selected, and display all of their documents.

I can't seem to figure out how to connect the facility clicked on the map with their associated list/library.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the GeoLocation field of SharePoint ? With it you can add the location of your offices in a list and create a map view and also add the URL document library/site of the respective office location in the view. Here are some references

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/create-a-map-view-for-the-geolocation-field-in-sharepoint

https://zimmergren.net/sp-2013-getting-started-with-the-new-geolocation-field-in-sharepoint-2013/

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/integrating-location-and-map-functionality-in-sharepoint

It requireds a valid bing map key though.